# How to get all transaction lists of local ethereum wallet using web3.py?

Tags: python, web3.py, django

I have developed django project that have local ethereum wallet using web3.py.
I want to get transaction history of my wallet.

But I have no way.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The following script fetches blocks and filters transactions to/from the given address. You can modify it to suit your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import json
import web3

from web3 import Web3
from hexbytes import HexBytes

# Exports transactions to a JSON file where each line
# contains the data returned from the JSONRPC interface

provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/')
w3 = Web3(provider)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('addr', type=str, help='Address to print the transactions for')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', type=str, help="Path to the output JSON file", required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start-block', type=int, help='Start block', default=0)
parser.add_argument('-e', '--end-block',  type=int, help='End block', default=w3.eth.blockNumber)

def tx_to_json(tx):
    result = {}
    for key, val in tx.items():
        if isinstance(val, HexBytes):
            result[key] = val.hex()
        else:
            result[key] = val

    return json.dumps(result)

def __main__():
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start_block = args.start_block
    end_block = args.end_block

    address_lowercase = args.addr.lower()

    ofile = open(args.output, 'w')

    for idx in range(start_block, end_block):
        print('Fetching block %d, remaining: %d, progress: %d%%'%(
            idx, (end_block-idx), 100*(idx-start_block)/(end_block-start_block)))

        block = w3.eth.getBlock(idx, full_transactions=True)

        for tx in block.transactions:
            if tx['to']:
                to_matches = tx['to'].lower() == address_lowercase
            else:
                to_matches = False

            if tx['from']:
                from_matches = tx['from'].lower() == address_lowercase
            else:
                from_matches = False

            if to_matches or from_matches:
                print('Found transaction with hash %s'%tx['hash'].hex())
                ofile.write(tx_to_json(tx)+'\n')
                ofile.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

Comment: Is there a way to check how much ETH is in each transaction thats found?

Comment: This works, but it is not possible to check all 17471079 blocks one by one and see if the desired address is located in which one. Is there no easier way? This is practically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of transactions of an Ethereum wallet address using the Etherscan API, you can follow the steps below:

1. Go to https://etherscan.io/apis and create an account.
2. Once you have created an account, generate an API key by going to
   "MyAPIs" in the top menu.
3. Select "Create a new API key", choose the "API" checkbox, and give
   your API key a name.
4. Once you've generated your API key, you can use it to make API
   requests.
5. To get a list of transactions for a particular Ethereum wallet address, you can make a GET request to the following endpoint:

`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=<ADDRESS>&startblock=<START_BLOCK>&endblock=<END_BLOCK>&sort=asc&apikey=<API_KEY>`

Replace  with the Ethereum wallet address you want to query. <START_BLOCK> and <END_BLOCK> are optional parameters that allow you to specify the block range for the transactions you want to retrieve. If you omit these parameters, all transactions will be returned. <API_KEY> should be replaced with the API key you generated earlier.

Here's an example of how you could make this request using cURL:

```
curl 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x742d35Cc6634C0532925a3b844Bc454e4438f44e&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=<API_KEY>'
```

This will return a JSON response containing the list of transactions for the specified Ethereum wallet address.